# Ubuntu server doesn't detect new disk using fdisk/cfdisk/parted

Tags: 16.04, server, partitioning, raid

I'm mounting a new (physical) server. I installed Ubuntu but it detects only sda (which is a RAID1) but didn't find a second disk (which is a RAID 5 of 3 disks) when I do `fdisk`:

[image: fdisk -l run as root, shows sda with 3 partitions]

My BIOS detected the disks and the RAID (I set up the RAID from my BIOS).

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Server: Lenovo ST550

Do you have any idea please?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to load the right driver for the specific RAID chipset on the machine. I went to the lenovo website and found

https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/servers/thinksystem/st550/7x09/downloads

They appear to only have driver packages for SUSE and RHEL; in short, they're only supporting the Red Hat flavours of linux, and not the Debian flavour (which is what Ubuntu is based on). It may be possible to install the drivers and have them work, but you're going to have to do it "by hand" as the drivers come in a rpm package, not a deb package.

You could try the alien package which can let you install rpms on debian flavours of linux (like ubuntu). You should be able to get it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien <file name of rpm>
```

It converts .rpm packages to .deb packages. Once you have a .deb package, you can run

```
sudo dpkg -i <file name of deb>
```

A quick google says you can also try

```
sudo alien -i <file name of rpm>
```

to just install it directly from the .rpm file.
If all looks all right, try rebooting the machine and see if the hardware RAID becomes available as a disk. Run your partitioner and set up volumes.

At that point, you're going to need to go into

```
/etc/fstab
```

and set the partitions up to be mounted at boot.

Good luck, and let everyone know if it works!